ncurses C home and end keys
I'm doing a simple menu with ncurses. It works for cygwin, but not in linux - home or end keys end the program immediately. I think handling of excape (27) has something to do with it because if I don't handle it in linux home and end have no effect. in cygwin - home, end and esc work fine (of course escape usually works which delay as it aways did in linux).
in my event loop I do this
  while (true) {
    clearScr = false;
    c = wgetch(menuWin);
    switch (c) {
      case KEY_HOME: {
        code = menu_driver(menu, REQ_FIRST_ITEM);
        break;
      }
      case KEY_END: {
        code = menu_driver(menu, REQ_LAST_ITEM);
        break;
      }
      case 27: {// Esc key - if I remove this home and end still doesn't work but they don't quit the program
        if (!isSubMenu) {
          // Handle cancel logic
          //are you sure?
        }
        return;
      }
...

I'm doing this when I create the menu
keypad(menuWin, TRUE);

my ncurses init/cleanup code:
void initialize_ncurses() {
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  intrflush(stdscr, FALSE); // Prevent flush on interrupt keys - ChatGPT advice
  start_color();
  init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
  init_pair(2, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE); // Selected text color pair
  init_pair(3, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
}

void cleanup_ncurses() {
  endwin();
}

I'm connecting to linux via putty. putty keyboard settings:


What is your TERM environment variable set to after connecting with putty (echo $TERM)?  Should be set to putty.

PuTTY's configuration dialog can produce combinations that don't correspond to any of the existing terminal descriptions.

@BradLanam I will try that. I tried xterm via XMing. home and end keys work fine. However in MC home and end keys work with putty too. so they are doing something different. also tried nmtui - home and end work in putty

Just tried to set 'Terminal type string' which changes the $TERM variable. now home and end keys work, so big thank for that. I don't know why it was xterm - maybe it's the default or maybe I changed it. I still would want to know how other text UI make it work even with putty with TERM=xterm.

@BradLanam Well setting term to putty broke the borders. borders now consist of letters l q x m k j  ... etc. MC (Midnight Commander) doesn't seem to care - it has nice borders and keys work properly with either of putty or xterm. Maybe I'm missing some initialization to switch border type?

The terminal as set by the TERM environment variable must match the terminal you are using.  Linux ships with many different putty configurations, but as @ThomasDickey says, there may be putty configurations that do not exist.
putty               putty+fnkeys+sco    putty-m1     putty+screen
putty-256color      putty+fnkeys+vt100  putty-m1b    putty-screen
putty+fnkeys        putty+fnkeys+vt400  putty-m2     putty-vt100
putty+fnkeys+esc    putty+fnkeys+xterm  putty-noapp
putty+fnkeys+linux  putty+keypad        putty-sco

I would be inclined to try TERM=putty+fnkeys+xterm (with putty set to Xterm R6 emulation).  You can also try TERM=xterm or TERM=vt100 and see if those might work.

I'm not sure I would entirely trust what other programs are doing.  Many programs nowadays have vt100 escape sequences hard-coded into their programs.  That works with most modern terminal emulations, but it isn't really the correct way to do it.

database comment: Entries with embedded plus signs are designed to be included through use/tc capabilities, not used as standalone entries.

Thanks! On centos I did  ls /usr/share/terminfo/p/|grep putty  to find what's supported: putty putty-256color putty-sco putty-vt100. And TERM=putty didn't brake the borders. I was linking to curses instead ncruses. So I'm accepting this as answer.  I still want to handle the escape sequences though...

For now I'm using the workaround that Brad Lanam suggested - to use Terminal-type string =  putty.
It's not an ideal solution because clearly it's possible to make it work with TERM=xterm as most text UI programs work without a problem. One idea is to manually non-blocking read a char after ESC and see if it follows the home/end key sequence. For example HOME triggers following chars: 27 91 49 126. But that seems like another nasty workaround. maybe ncurses has something built in to do that.
The other problem with using letters as border instead of drawing symbols was because I used this cmake setup I found on internet:
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})

This links against curses, not ncruses. One way to link against ncurses is (if anyone knows better solution, please tell me):
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED )
pkg_check_modules ( ncursesw REQUIRED ncursesw )
pkg_check_modules ( menuw REQUIRED menuw )
pkg_check_modules ( formw REQUIRED formw )

target_link_libraries(app ${ncursesw_LIBRARIES} ${menuw_LIBRARIES} ${formw_LIBRARIES} )

I'm not marking this as answer because MC and other TUI programs show that there is more universal approach, but it'll do short term.
